# Elasticsearch indexing not working and error message: node null not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I just downloaded the elastic search distribution and ran it.

```
curl 'localhost:9200'

{
   "status" : 200,
   "name" : "cbs",
   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
   "version" : {
   "number" : "1.4.1",
   "build_hash" : "89d3241d670db65f994242c8e8383b169779e2d4",
   "build_timestamp" : "2014-11-26T15:49:29Z",
   "build_snapshot" : false,
   "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
    },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And I am trying to access it using spring-data.
Added the following lines in application-context (as per spring data documentation) with xml namespace:

```
<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.cbs" />
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="127.0.0.1:9300" cluster-name="elasticsearch" />
<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
</bean>
```

Here is the entity and repository code:

```
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "product", type = "product", shards = 1, replicas = 0, indexStoreType = "memory", refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;    
    private String name;
}


@Repository
public class ProductSearchDaoImpl implements IProductSearchDao {
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

@Override
public void index(Product product) {
    elasticsearchOperations.createIndex(Product.class);
    elasticsearchOperations.putMapping(Product.class);
    IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(product.getId()).withObject(product).build();
    elasticsearchOperations.index(indexQuery);
    elasticsearchOperations.refresh(Product.class, true);
}
}
```

Now when I run the test case to index the product, I am getting a consistent warning message (every 2 seconds or so) as

```
[Neuronne] node null not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...
[Neuronne] node null not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...
```

And the product is not getting indexed (even the index is not created)

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index    pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 40):

For those who met the same error and came here from search engines, make sure the `TransportClient` is using the same cluster name as the cluster itself.

1. Verify cluster name.

Visit http://localhost:9200 to check the cluster name. The default name is `elasticsearch`. If you customised the cluster name using `elasticsearch.yml` file, make sure the config file is picked up.

2. Set `culster.name` when creating `TransportClient`.

   ```
   Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
           .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
           .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
           .put("node.client", true)
           .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
           .build();
   client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new  InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port));
   ```
3. Ignore cluster name check

You can ignore the check of cluster name by setting `client.transport.ignore_cluster_name` to `true`.

4. Debug if the error still exists

If the error still exists, launch your application in debug mode, and debug [`TransportClientNodesService`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/4c981ff4bfc250080d521af105b5e8589c9fc517/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClientNodesService.java#L468).

Comment: Most of the cases, this error happens only when the transport client has the wrong cluster name!

Comment: I just disabled the cluster name check, for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had changed name on my dev elasticsearch server for the sake of experimenting and forgot about it.

The error message on the client were not that helpful, TransportClientNodeService makes a compare with the remote name but doesn't actually write the remote name ("cluster-name")in the log.

It is possible to bypass the name check with the following Spring configuration:

The resolution for me was to either:

- Change name of the cluster.name in elasticsearch server.
- Ignore cluster name of the client.

I went for both, this is my Spring config, hope it helps:

```
spring:
    ...
    data:
    elasticsearch:
        # Defaults to cluster-name 'elasticsearch'
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes: 127.0.0.1:9300
        properties:
            # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html
            client.transport.ignore_cluster_name: true
```